# Django 1.8 migrating local postgres database into a heroku database

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, django-database, django-deployment

I've been stuck on this part for a while.After completing all the other steps when I enter `git push heroku master`, it pushes all the files but how do I migrate my local database? There are no commands for that. My `settings.py` file is still pointing to the local postgres database.How do I migrate this data into the heroku database?

`settings.py`

```
 DATABASES = {
   'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'music',                      
    'USER': '**',
    'PASSWORD': '**',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you followed the heroku django tutorial. From the [django-settings](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#django-settings) they are clearly mention how heroku will detect database url using `dj-database-url` package.

So just define this setting below your `settings.py` file then you are good to go.

For Importing and Exporting to heroku postgres please see this [heroku-postgres-import-export](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)